# Grouping and sum JSON array in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

My JSON is look like this

```
[ 

{t_id :"1",  val1 : "1" ,   title:"cash to purchase",   unit :"bag"},

{t_id :"1"  ,val1 : "1" ,  title:"cash to purchase", unit :"bag"}

{t_id :"1",val1 : "1" , title:"cash to purchase", unit :"bag"}

{t_id :"2",val1 : "4" , title:"offload", unit :"bag"},

{t_id :"2",val1 : "5" , title:"onroad", unit :"bag"},

{t_id :"3", val1 : "5" , title:"Onroad", unit :"bag"},

{t_id :"3", val1 : "6" , title:"Onroad", unit :"bag"},

]
```

I want to group by t_id  and find the sum of val1 according to each t_id ..then i want out on my HTML like

> Title:cash to purchase
>
> bag:3
>
> Title:Offload
>
> bag:9
>
> title:onroad
>
> bag:11

Comment: are you sure thats json? why is there `=`?

Comment: you can try out `groupBy` in lodash. [**documentation**](https://lodash.com/docs/#groupBy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. End to end **Complete solution**:

```js
var array = [{t_id:"1",val1:"1",title:"cash to purchase",unit:"bag"},{t_id:"1",val1:"1",title:"cash to purchase",unit:"bag"},{t_id:"1",val1:"1",title:"cash to purchase",unit:"bag"},{t_id:"2",val1:"4",title:"offload",unit:"bag"},{t_id:"2",val1:"5",title:"onroad",unit:"bag"},{t_id:"3",val1:"5",title:"Onroad",unit:"bag"},{t_id:"3",val1:"6",title:"Onroad",unit:"bag"}];

var grouped = [];

array.forEach(function(o) {
  if (!this[o.t_id]) {
    this[o.t_id] = {
      t_id: o.t_id,
      val1: 0,
      title: o.title
    };
    grouped.push(this[o.t_id]);
  }
  this[o.t_id].val1 += Number(o.val1);
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
$scope.results = grouped;
```

Copy below code into your HTML:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item class="" ng-repeat="result in results">
        <div class="item item-text-wrap">
          Title: {{result.title}}
          <br>
          Bag: {{result.val1}}
        </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: @Arjun Ramdas, did you check my answer?

Comment: yes..it's working...Is it is possible to divide the val1(ie sum) by total number of t_id..which means there are three t_id :'1' so i need to download the total sum(val1) by total t_id

Comment: Yes that’s also possible, will do it tomorrow. For the time being accept this answer and upvote because it’s currently fulfilling your requirements

Comment: it's very emergency to divide by total t_id by total sum(val1)....i already upvoted

Comment: it's okay...do if u can tomorrow..thanks Vic...you done a great job..if i  get early answer then i can close my project...

Comment: @ArjunRamdas, can you post it as a separate question for better clarification, as I am not able to understand it correctly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547701/grouping-json-array-with-sum

Answer (score 1):

Make a new object to store the sum of all the `value` w.r.t `t_id` as

```
var groupObj = {};
list.forEach( ele => 
    groupObj[ele.t_id] = groupObj[ele.t_id] ? 
          {title: ele.title, sum: groupObj[ele.t_id].sum + Number(ele.val1)} :
          {title: ele.title, sum: Number(ele.val1) }
);
```

This will make `groupObj` as

```
{
    1: { title: "cash to purchase", sum: 3 },
    2: { title: "onroad", sum: 9 },
    3: { title: "Onroad", sum: 11 }
}
```

Add comments if you need further help.

Comment: Is it possible to push the title and sum to an array?

Comment: `b` is the list.... updated.......also in array it wont be possible for you to find any `t_id`....you can make it but will have to iterate over it again and again.

Comment: let me know if need help to iterate over this object or need array code also.